# Is there a full list somewhere of the audio file types the Web Audio API can use?

Tags: web-audio-api

I'm assuming that the file types that can be played back from the web audio api are limited by the browser vendors.
I'm curious if there is a particular list of audio file types that can be played back that are specific to the web audio api (or if its all just 'data' so to speak and again, its up to the browser vendors). From what I've read the file types seem to parallel the audio element.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Have you seen [Web Audio Codecs List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_Audio) on wikipedia?

Comment: That list is for codecs for the <audio> element , not the web audio api  hence my question regarding the distinction.

Comment: Browsers support the same audio formats for <audio> and web audio. In fact [SoundJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/SoundJS) determines support for web audio using an audio tag canPlayType method.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed up to the vendor, and in fact it's usually somewhat platform-dependent.

Chrome supports MP3, WAV and OGG at a minimum; Firefox supports WAV and OGG, and MP3 on some platforms, if memory serves.  Safari supports MP3 and WAV, but no OGG.

Comment: Can you tell me if the web audio api will LOAD a buffer of an audio file than can't be played back in the browser that is making the request? In other words if a browser can NOT playback/recognize an ogg file will the web audio api still load it in a buffer even though the browser cant play it , or will the web audio api abstain from even attempting to load it. I think this is my real question but I didn't know how to phrase it.

Comment: If the browser can't decode the file type, it should do nothing (call the error callback, I mean, not the success callback) - it should NOT put the bits in the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

As from your comment to cwilso's answer, I just tried loading image files (which are obviously not music). It does trigger an error to that. For audio files of which you suspect they do not work I suggest you to [try them out yourself](http://jsbin.com/hekugofa/1/edit) to see if they generate an error (I do not have a file nor appropriate browser(like safari) to test right now).